# coordinate transformation of the local pull back of the Maurer Cartan form

Tags: differential-geometry

This questions asks how to express the pull back of the Mauere Cartan form on a Lie group to a smooth manifold.

The Lie group,$G$, is the structure group of a smooth vector bundle over the manifold,$M$.

The maps $F_{ab}$ map the intersection $U_{ab} = U_a \cap U_b$ of coordinate neighborhoods into $G$ and satisfy the rule,

$F_{ac} = F_{ab}\cdot F_{bc}$

If $W_{ab}$ denotes the pull back of the Maurer Cartan form to $U_{ab}$ then its coordinate transformation rule is

$$ W_{ac} = \operatorname{ad}(F_{bc})W_{ab} + W_{bc}$$

How is this formula derived?

Comment: I tried to write the math types in tex code. I hope I have no mistakes

Comment: (a) for future reference, this site supports MathJax (which Dimitris was kind enough to insert into the post for you). See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial. (b) Technically you need to be a bit more careful when stating the definition of the transition map. The property you wrote is only true on $U_a \cap U_b \cap U_c$. Otherwise your bundle is automatically trivial.